# What does "All your responses for all questions should not exceed one page" mean?

Tags: meaning

I am presented with six questions that I'm required to respond to in writing. Some of the questions are:

1. What do you believe in?
2. What learning experiences have had the greatest impact in your life? etc etc.

The only instruction given is that:

> All your responses for all questions should not exceed one page.

What does that mean? I am torn between two possibilities:

1. The answers to each question must not exceed one page (my final submission should be at most six pages).
2. The answers to all six questions must not exceed one page (my final submission should be at most one page).

Comment: To me, it’s one page for all questions. But perhaps they meant the first.

Comment: Ask the question setter for clarity.

Comment: @Xanne Exactly my thoughts.

Comment: @WeatherVane I would have to wait until Monday.

Comment: Then write two versions, if that is the deadline too. Start with the fuller page-per-answer and condense the most important points from each.

Comment: 'No single answer should be longer than one page' or 'You must not submit more than a single page in total, in spite of there being six complex/multi-point questions'? Doesn't pragmatics make one interpretation nonsensical? What does previous experience with such exercises make seem reasonable? But the instructions _are_ really poor.

Comment: Limit all answers to a single page? Great. Don’t ask back, just do it. In the unlikely case it was meant as one page for *each* answer, there was no “each” or “every”, and you are golden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All: pronoun, singular or plural in construction
>
> the whole number, quantity, or amount : TOTALITY; "all that I have"; "all of us"; "all of the books".
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all)

The *all* in "all questions" stands for the totality of the questions.

The *all* in "all your responses" stands for the totality of your responses.

At the most basic level, omitting the qualifying phrase "for all questions", the instructions say: "All your responses should not exceed one page." This means that the totality of your responses should not exceed one page.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, you have provided verifiable evidence. Who am I to argue with that?

Comment: A kind remark, thank you. But you must please respect your own right to argue with any of us here. We are not infallible, we are not authorities, and we make mistakes. Nevertheless, we try to help.

Comment: Sure. Duly noted.